# Period of a stationary wave VS Period of vibration of a stationary wave

Tags: waves, terminology, vibrations

Is there any difference between these terms? I tried to find on Google, but couldn't. In a question I was attempting, it stated the period of vibration of stationary wave and in the answer, it implied that period of the wave is twice the period of vibration of that stationary wave. Hence, I am confused. I think it's an error?

Answer (score 0):

Those two expressions mean the same thing.

If the stationary wave is created by two traveling waves traveling in opposite directions and interfering, then the period of the stationary wave is also equal to the period of the traveling waves.

What you might have seen is that the amplitude of a stationary wave is double the amplitude of the traveling waves that formed it.